# File not found error in Laravel Excel while importing file

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel Excel in my Laravel 4.2 project.
I tried to import simple xls file but I am getting error because of slashes. I am using windows development environment currently. I know this error will be gone if I will use linux development environment. Please help me how to get rid of following error. Problem is about slashes.

Error: 
`Could not open C:\xampp\htdocs\campusc/tpstudentupload.xls for reading! File does not exist.`

following is my code written in controller.

```
public function upload(){
    try {
        $result = Excel::selectSheets('Sheet1')->load("tpstudentupload.xls",function($reader){
        })->get();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)

Or define your own

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')           
    define('DS', '\\');
else 
    define('DS', '/');
```

And then replace all slashes with `DS` or `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`